# Identify Comuter is in Domain or Workgroup?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is there a quick way to identify whether a computer is member of `domain` or `workgroup` using batch script? If it is the member of `domain`, What is the `domain`'s name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to find it with powershell and capture it output in batch variable.

Following is the code

```
@echo off
REM Bellow logic is to identify "Computer membership"? True=Member of domain | False=Member of Workgroup
for /f %%a in ('powershell "(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).PartOfDomain"') do set ComMem=%%a
echo %ComMem%

If %ComMem% Equ True    (
                        GoTo Domainmember
                        ) Else  (
                                GoTo WorkgroupMember
                                )


REM Bellow logic is will find Domain / Workgroup Name

:Domainmember

for /f %%f in ('powershell "(Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain"') do set MemNme=%%f
Pause
GoTo End
:WorkgroupMember
for /f %%f in ('powershell "(Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Workgroup"') do set MemNme=%%f

:End
Echo %MemNme%
pause
```